# VS2010 - add custom compiler for certain file extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, command-line, opencl

I've written a command-line OpenCL compiler. I'd like to have VS compile my kernel source files using this whenever I build the C# project that includes them. I've looked around and found information and custom build tasks, custom tools, etc, but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly.

1. How can I tell VS to run my exe on the source files in the same way that it runs the c# compiler, etc for other files in the project?
2. I report errors from this tool by calling `Console.Error.WriteLine()`. This dutifully places the errors in the Output pane, where I can double-click them, taking me to the appropriate place in the .cl kernel source file. However, the errors don't appear in the VS error panel. ??

Alternatively, if anyone's aware of an existing OpenCL compiler - it's annoying to have to *run* the host application just to compile the kernel - I'd appreciate a link.

I've managed to get this working by adding a post-build step to the project options. However, I'd really prefer for this exe to be run for every *.cl file in the project.

**Update** I had neglected to include an error code when formatting my error messages. Correcting them to match [any of the formats listed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx) took care of that issue. Still trying to figure out how to associate an exe with a given file extension, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer for you here. But, I just wanted to add a warning.  You really do want to compile your *.cl files on the user's machine so that the user's device can make any appropriate optimizations.  Not to mention that a *.cl file compiled from (say) an NVIDIA driver won't run on (say) an ATI card.

Comment: @Jonathan - agreed, this is strictly for development purposes. Even with the post-build step I'm using now (which is kind of a hack), the kernels are recompiled at runtime by the driver. This approach, though, makes debugging a LOT easier.